# Synonym Request: [text-file] ⇒ [text-files]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

Should [text-file](/questions/tagged/text-file) and [text-files](/questions/tagged/text-files) merged, and [text-file](/questions/tagged/text-file) made a synonym?

There are 66 questions using [text-file](/questions/tagged/text-file), and 1,047 questions using [text-files](/questions/tagged/text-files).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completed: [text-file](/questions/tagged/text-file) and [text-files](/questions/tagged/text-files) merged, and [text-file](/questions/tagged/text-file) made a synonym